# Java - What's <> used and what's its name?

Tags: java, generics

I'm working through some sample code and then this appeared:

```
public abstract class RandomPool<T> extends Pool {
     //Class...
}
```

What's `<>` used for? And why is just `T` inside these? This seems to be very random for me. However, how can I use it in a longer perspective of making programs?

Thanks and tell me if I need to add more details!

Comment: Thanks for answering everyone! I will read through the Java Generics docs and make sure I understand everything - then I will accept the most describing answer based on my understanding from the docs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Java Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

T stands for "Type"

Comment: Is it necessary to be just T or can I use any letter as I wish?

Answer (score 3):

**Generics**

`T` is a placeholder for whatever type is used at runtime. For example you could use:

```
RandomPool<String> pool;
```

`T` would refer to `String` in that case.

Read the [Java Generics Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

That thing is called a **type parameter**.

Basically, your class `RandomPool` is a generic class. It has a type parameter so that it could use different classes provided by caller. See Java collections like [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) it will be much more clear.

Also, note that `T` is not a keyword, you could name the type parameter any way you like. It's just a convention to use T  like Type. Some collections use E like Element.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you declare the type of a Generic that your class accepts.  The example you presented reads:

abstract class ObjectPool of type T extends Pool

Answer (score 1):

very short desc T is a compiler variable.  with your code posted you can have a randomPool of Strings, eg: `RandomPool<String>` a randomPool of Foos, `eg: RandomPoo<Foo>`, .... Pretty much anything.

read dom farr's link with this in mind

Answer (score 1):

It's the java way (Generics) to implement templates (in C++). T represents the type of the element you want to use for a particular object instantiated.

You can easily understand generics by looking at this example:

```
Hashmap <String, int> hm = new HashMap<String,int>();
hm.put("k1",1);
hm.put("k2",2);

Iterator it = hm.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()){
    String curr = it.next();
    int value = hm.get(curr);
}
```

Here, you can understand that Hashmap takes 2 types (general types, you can use whatever you want.. from Natives to custom classes etc etc). 
RandomPool, in the example you posted, should be instantiated with a particular custom type! So, when you decide to use it, you should write code this way (i.e.):

```
RandomPool<String> myR = new RandomPool<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing fancy about this. It's just Java's syntax for rank-1 parametric polymorphism.